# The value of Gravitational Chern Simons theory integration on some three manifolds

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, mathematical-physics, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

Consider the 3d gravitational Chern Simons theory 
$$S= \frac{k}{192 \pi} \int_{M_3} \mathrm{Tr}\left(\omega\; \mathrm{d} \omega + \frac{2}{3}\omega^3\right)$$
where $\omega$ is the spin-connection on $M_3$. For the theory to be well defined, $k$ has to be an integer. I am interested to know what is the precise value of this integral for certain $M_3$. For instance, when $M_3= \mathbb{R}^3$, the integration clearly vanishes.

(1): What about $M_3= \mathbf{T}^3$ (the three torus with length $R$ along each direction), $\mathbf{S}^3$ (the three sphere with radius $R$) and $\mathbb{RP}^3= \mathbf{S}^3/\mathbb{Z}_2$ ($\mathbf{S}^3$ of radius $R$ with anti-pode identified)?

(2): Are there compact closed manifolds that can distinguish all the $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ class (i.e., for different $k$, $e^{iS}$ yields different phases. )?

p.s.: We know that on a $M_3$ with bdry, the brdy can have chiral central charge $c= k/2$ hence probes the value of $k$.

Any results or references will be helpful.